Optimal Timing for Structural Break Analysis in Price Transmission Modeling
I am investigating the price transmission between two inflation indices within the same sector but at different stages of processing. For example, I might be looking at the relationship between raw milk prices and retail cheese prices. My goal is to analyze and estimate the lead-lag relationship and price transmission between these two series using both an Autoregressive Distributed Lag (ADL) model and a Vector Autoregression (VAR) model.
My current workflow involves the following steps:

Taking the natural logarithm of both series;
Applying Seasonal-Trend decomposition using LOESS (STL) to remove seasonality;
Differencing the series to achieve stationarity.

However, I realize I haven't accounted for potential structural breaks in the data. My question is:
At what stage in my workflow should I ideally conduct structural break analysis?
Should I:

Test for breaks before any transformations (i.e., on the raw data)?
Test after taking the logarithm but before STL decomposition?
Test after STL decomposition but before differencing?
Or should I test for breaks after achieving stationarity (i.e., after differencing)?

Given my goal of modeling price transmission using ADL and VAR models, I'd appreciate the community's guidance on when to conduct break testing to ensure the most accurate and reliable estimates of the lead-lag relationship and price transmission dynamics.
